# Darkmode + Changing source of pictures

Tags: javascript, html

So I had implement dark mode to my website but there are pictures that I need to change for it to function properly. I have the light and dark versions of the images that I need but I would like to know if there's any way I can change the source of the image when I enable dark mode.

I got my code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wodWDIdV9BY

This is my button for darkmode and the image in HTML:

```
<button onclick="changeImage();" id="dark-mode-toggle" class="dark-mode-toggle">Darkmode On/Off</button>
```

The Javascript to enable darkmode (refer to youtube link above):

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle');
const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}
if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
  enableDarkMode();
}

darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 
  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});
```

***This is what I had tried***

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 

const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle');

const enableDarkMode = () => {

    document.getElementById('icon').src="images/twar-white-icon.png"

  document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {

    document.getElementById('icon').src="images/twar-black-icon.png"

  document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}
if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
  enableDarkMode();
}

darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 
  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});
```

Basicly what I added was  `document.getElementById('icon').src="images/twar-white-icon.png"` and `document.getElementById('icon').src="images/twar-black-icon.png"`

But I kept getting an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"
at my console log. I need the source of image to change as darkmode in enabled and disable because the function was saved on localStorage which remembers the setting made on the previous visit. The source of the image has to be based on whether darkmode was enabled or not.

Comment: You need image object with id icon in your html. If not it will generate this error

Comment: Can you check your network tab and see whether the dark mode image is being loaded, after you toggle the mode? If not, you could also try to load both images into separate img sections and change the visibility on toggle.

Comment: Thanks guys but I have already solved it. Yes it was not reading the id of the icon because I had put the script tag above where the img tag was written. I had put it down the body so I can make more source changes which have seemed to work thus far. Thank you anyways, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript written was correct, but I was receiving error messages that the id was null. This was because I had put the script tag above the image tag and once I shifted it down the body tag, it read the id and carried out the function.